AWS Kinesis Data Stream to SQS
I need to send certain Kinesis Data Stream events to an SQS queue, but as far as I can tell, Kinesis Data Stream cannot directly populate a queue (KDS cannot be an event source for SQS as far as I can tell). Am I misunderstand here? Has anyone directly written KDS events to an SQS queue?
As far as I can tell, I only have two options:

Intermediary Lambda that is triggered by the KDS, processes events, sends events to SQS
Kinesis Firehose

